# How do I select items in MenuBar (PyQt/Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

I have created the menu bar shown below as part of a `QMainWindow` Class and i wanted to run another `class` or `def` when i click on `'Save as...'` in the `Menubar`. How could i edit the code below to allow me to do that?? By The way, when i click on `Quit`, it works (it closes the `MainWindow`).

```
def createMenusAndToolbars(self):
        fileMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu("File")
        for text in (("Save As..."), ("Quit")):
            action = QtGui.QAction(text, self)
            if text == "Save As...":
                text.clicked.connect(self.save)
            if text == "Quit":
                self.connect(action, QtCore.SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.close)
            fileMenu.addAction(action)
def save(self):
    save = SaveTest(self)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted is essentially correct, except for one obviously wrong line. Here's a simplified version which should work as you intended:

```
def createMenusAndToolbars(self):
    fileMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu('File')
    fileMenu.addAction('Save As...', self.save)
    fileMenu.addAction('Quit', self.quit)

def save(self):
    save = SaveTest(self)
```

NB: the [addAction](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmenu.html#addAction-3) method returns the action it creates, which would allow you to set other properties, if necessary.